# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'host')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

Im keep getting that error while having no idea why. Im trying to connect to my mongodb database but it keeps telling me that "host" is undefined!

Here are my files:

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

//Load config
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });
console.log("hello");
connectDB();

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

The error is in db.js line 11

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      //   useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    console.log("hey!");
    console.log(`MongoDB connecteed: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Please let me know if im missing anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should `await` `mongoose.connect` which returns a `Promise`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      //   useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connecteed: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely because `conn.connection` is null, and you're trying to access the property `host` on it.

Try logging `conn` rather than `conn.connection.host`.

Comment: can you please explain how come its null?. Also, wouldnt it be differnet if i did conn instead?

Comment: it should be defined, there is probably something else going on, but it must be null if you are getting that error (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'host')`).

Comment: I did define it in the try block tho, no?.  Also, wouldnt it be differnet if i did conn instead?

Comment: You defined conn, and `mongoose.connect` should define the rest, but that error clearly indicates that it is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

you were getting that error, because await wasn't being used, and after compiling no value is assigned to 'conn' as mongodb connection takes time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35427749)